# Understanding VS performance analysis

Tags: c#, performance, boxing

I have a C# assembly which processes retail promotions. It is able to process a promotion that has 1,288 qualifying products in just 7 seconds. However, where it is tasked to process a promotion with a larger number of qualifying products then the time taken increases exponentially in relation to the number of products. For example, a promo with 29,962 products takes 7 mins 7 secs and a promo with 77,350 products takes 39 mins and 7 secs.

I've been trying to identify if there's code in the assembly that can be easily optimized. I set the assembly processing the largest of the promotions then attached the performance analyzer to the containing process (BizTalk host instance), the resulted in the following report:

[image]

This suggests that the function taking the greatest amount of time is "GetDataPromoLines". This function contains simple string formatting. It is called from the following loop of the function "MapForFF":

```
foreach (var promoLine in promoLineChunk.PromoLines)
{
    outputFile = outputFile + GetDataPromoLines(promoLine, promoLineNumber+1);
    promoLineNumber++;
}
```

The promoLineChunck.PromoLines is a List of a class which describes the promotion, it contains only private strings - one for each column of the database table from which the promotion details were selected. The content of the "GetDataPromoLines" function can be seen below:

```
private string GetDataPromoLines(VW_BT_PROMOTIONSRECORDSELECT promoLine, int sequenceNumber)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    string seqNum = sequenceNumber.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
    string uniqueNumber = promoLine.CIMS_PROMO_NUMBER + seqNum;

    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("PromoDiscount,\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\",\"{5}\",\"{6}\",\"{7}\"",
        uniqueNumber,
        promoLine.CIMS_PROMO_NAME,
        promoLine.TYPE,
        promoLine.DESCRIPTION_,
        promoLine.DISCOUNTLEVEL,
        promoLine.COUPONNUMBERMIN,
        promoLine.COUPONNUMBERMAX,
        promoLine.COUPONNUMBERLENGTH
        ));

    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("ItemReq,\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\",\"{5}\",\"{6}\",\"{7}\",\"{8}\"",
        "00001",
        promoLine.IDENTITYTYPE,
        promoLine.ITEMNUM,
        promoLine.DIVISIONNUM,
        promoLine.DEPARTMENTNUM,
        promoLine.DEPTGROUPNUM,
        promoLine.CLASSNUM,
        promoLine.ITEMGROUPNUM,
        promoLine.IR_QUANTITY
        ));

    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("TierDefinition,\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\",\"{5}\",\"{6}\",\"{7}\",\"{8}\"",
        "00001",
        promoLine.THRESHOLDTYPE,
        promoLine.THRESHOLDQTY,
        promoLine.THRESHOLDAMT,
        promoLine.DISCTYPE,
        promoLine.DISCPCT,
        promoLine.DISCAMT,
        promoLine.DISCAPPLIESTO,
        promoLine.DISCQTY,
        promoLine.ADDLINFO
        ));

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Can anyone suggest what is causing the exponential increase in time to process? Is it something to do with CLR unboxing?

Comment: An exponential slowdown is almost certainly algorithmic so you should look at that instead of worrying about boxing.

Comment: What happens in term of performance, if you just call GetDataPromoLines() without concatenting the result to outputFile ?

Comment: Use `sb.AppendFormat` instread of `sb.AppendLine` plus `string.Format`

Comment: string.Format is probably an order of magnitude slower than string concatenation in this case. Maybe more. It involves parsing a format string and doing all kinds of runtime stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`outputFile = outputFile + GetDataPromoLines(promoLine, promoLineNumber+1);`

Is that an attempt to build an entire output file by appending strings? There's your Schlemiel.

For cases like this, you really want to use `StringBuilder` (or even better, output directly into a file stream using `StreamWriter` or something):

```
StringBuilder outputFile;

foreach (var promoLine in promoLineChunk.PromoLines)
{
  outputFile.Append(GetDataPromoLines(promoLine, promoLineNumber+1));
  promoLineNumber++;
}
```

The problem with simple appends is that `string` is immutable in .NET - every time you modify it, it is copied over. For things like outputting huge text files, this is incredibly costly, of course - you spend most of your time copying the parts of the string that didn't change.

The same way, don't do `sb.AppendLine(string.Format(...));` - simply use `sb.AppendFormat`. Ideally, pass the `StringBuilder` as an argument, to avoid having to copy over the lines themselves - although that should be relatively insignificant performance hit next to the `outputFile += ...`.

As a side-note, be careful when interpreting the results of profiling - it's often subtly misleading. In your case, I'm pretty certain your problem is not in `GetDataPromoLines` itself (although even that could be improved, as seen above), but in the `outputFile += ...`. It's not enough to just look at the function with the highest exclusive samples. It's also not enough to just look at the hot path, although that's already a huge step-up that usually leads you straight where your attention is needed. Also, understand the difference between sampling and instrumentation - sampling can often lead you to try optimizing a method that's not really a performance problem on its own - rather, it simply shouldn't be called as often as it is. Do not use profiler results as blindfolds - you still need to pay attention to what actually makes *sense*.

Comment: I changed the call within the foreach look to use a string builder (don't know how I missed this in the first place!) and the results were dramatic. Time to process the largest of the promotions decreased from 39mins 7 seconds to 35 seconds. Thanks for your help :)